# How to manage only one oneToMany entity in parent form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an Entity `Criteria` which can have several Entity `Vote` (associated).
I want to DISPLAY a list of criteria and to show only ONE Vote form in front of each Criteria (not zero, not many), to allow user to vote for each Criteria.

But, as I have a oneToMany association, in my CriteriaForm, I must have a CollectionType of Vote (I think ?). I tried to have only a VoteType :

```
$builder->add('votesCritere', VoteCritereType::class);
```

but I have an error :

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class LabelBundle\Entity\VoteCritere, but is an instance of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
```

So I think I must have a CollectionType. But, if I have a collection type, I start with ZERO form (because My Criteria does not contain any Vote yet).

I want to have only (and always) one Vote form in front of each criteria, to **add** a vote to the criteria (I don't want the number of forms reflects the number of votes)

How can I do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: So, you need a list of checkboxes (or ... ) based only on list of Criterias - right? Or vote has some properties to fill in?

Comment: Criterias will not be modified. Only Votes for each criteria (and will not be required). Votes will have two radio button and a textarea to fill a note.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think out loudly - in case you use entity bind form with collection type for votes, it'll allways show all of yours votes that would be bind to each criteria.

In this case I would recommend the array of forms based on criteria entity IDs.

Create Vote form type:

```
class VoteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Yes' => true,
                    'No' => false,
                )
            ))
            ->add('note', TextareaType::class),
            ->add('criteriaId', HiddenType::class),
            ->add('vote', SubmitType::class);
    ...
    ...
}
```

In the controller - get traversable of criterias (e.g. method findAll() method of repository) and create array of named forms based on criteria entity IDs:

```
$ff = $this->get('form.factory');
foreach ($criterias as $criteria) {
    $voteForms[] = $ff->createNamedBuilder(
        'vote_'.$criteria->getId(),
        new VoteType,
        array(
            'criteriaId' => $criteria->getId()
        )
    )
    ->getForm()
    ->createView();

}

return $this->render(someView, array("voteForms" => $forms));
```

And when the form is submitted then you can identify to which criteria the vote belongs by the hidden criteriaId field.

**EDIT - Added: How to submit all forms with one button**

'criteriaId' field and 'vote' submit in the VoteType is no longer needed - so:

```
class VoteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answer', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Yes' => true,
                    'No' => false,
                )
            ))
            ->add('note', TextareaType::class);
    ...
    ...
}
```

And in the controller just create form with VoteTypes members:

```
$fb = $this->createFormBuilder();
foreach ($criterias as $criteria) {
    $fb->add('vote-criteria-'.$criteria->getId(), VoteType::class);
}
$fb->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
$frm = $fb->getForm();

$frm->handleRequest($request);

if ($frm->isSubmitted() && $frm->isValid()) {
    // all criteria vote data
    $frm->getData();
    ...
}

return $this->render(someView, array('form' => $frm->createView()));
```

Comment: Thanks Honza, seems to be a good idea. But if I can, I would prefer submitting all the forms with one click (because I have a globalVote too, and to make a vote on each criteria, I must make the globalVote, so I must not permit to do only one criteriaVote). Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, I see what you want me to do. But I think I have made quite the same thing using embedded forms. So, the form expect me to add a CollectionType as I can have several Vote for each Criteria. If I put a CollectionType, I have no form (maybe because I have no Vote yet ?). I don"t want the number of form corresponding to the number of Votes, but always one and only one form. Maybe I misunderstand something ?

Comment: If you have an entity bound form, it always depends on the actual entity's state. So in your case if the criteria doesn't have any vote yet, than no form is rendered, resp. if you want one than you have to assign new vote entity to the criteria before rendering the form. Is it understandable?

Comment: Ok, I see ! But in the case I already have several vote, I will have several forms displayed. How can I avoid this, without deleting all the votes ?

Comment: That's how the entity bound form works - it's great for editing existing data, but for your particular demand you can't simply ommit existing records. That's why I suggest the solution above.